# How to display the recent added data to the top of the recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an app where i am storing data to firebase and retriving it to my reclycler view and but   issue is, i want to display the most recent added data to the top of the recycler view. I am trying to get the latest data and I had done all possibly Solution still I am not getting.

please see the following code....

here is my Mainclass:

```
public class ShowDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
List<DataClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_details);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.erecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ShowDetails.this));
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowDetails.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data from Firebase Database");
    progressDialog.show();

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("1:102738125513:android:3042292623f0448c") // Required for Analytics.
            .setApiKey("AIzaSyAZbWBpPzjAkrg23riK9kwk2T0tDf47dko") // Required for Auth.
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://citycare-fed31.firebaseio.com/") // Required for RTDB.
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
            // Retrieve my other app.
            FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("[DEFAULT]");
    // Get the database for the other app.
    FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
    DatabaseReference data = secondaryDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Electricity");
    data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {

                    DataClass DataClass = dSnapshot.getValue(DataClass.class);

                    Log.d("Show", DataClass.getEname() == null ? "" : DataClass.getEname());
                    list.add(DataClass);

                }
                adapter = new ShowDetails.DataAdapter(ShowDetails.this, list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

and this is my Adapter class:

```
 private class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShowDetails.DataAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    Context context;
    List<DataClass> listData;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<DataClass> list) {

        this.context = context;
        this.listData = list;
    }

    @Override
    public ShowDetails.DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.show_items, parent, false);
        ShowDetails.DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new ShowDetails.DataAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ShowDetails.DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final DataClass AllDetails = listData.get(position);
        holder.NameTextView.setText(AllDetails.getEname());
        holder.EmailTextView.setText(AllDetails.getEemail());
        holder.DateTextView.setText(AllDetails.getEdate());
        holder.LocationTextView.setText(AllDetails.getElocation());
        holder.TypeTextView.setText(AllDetails.getEtype());
        Picasso.with(context).load(AllDetails.getImgurl()).resize(120, 60).into(holder.ImageTextView);

        holder.ImageTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ShowDetails.this, ShowImage.class);
                i.putExtra("img", AllDetails.getImgurl());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ShowDetails.this, Email_Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("txt", AllDetails.getEemail());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView NameTextView;
        public TextView EmailTextView;
        public TextView DateTextView;
        public TextView LocationTextView;
        public TextView TypeTextView;
        public ImageView ImageTextView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            NameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowNameTextView);
            EmailTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowEmailTextView);
            DateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowDateTextView);
            LocationTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowLocationTextView);
            TypeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowTypeTextView);
            ImageTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShowImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

here is my database

[firebase data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRPqv.png)

here is my API response after removing extra for loop 
[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDMvZ.png)

please help me out i am new to programming

Comment: Please post database Structure

Comment: Please share your API response which you have to retrieve from the database. so we can help better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your data to list's first iterator in loop,
and move setadapter out of loops:

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
   for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : ds.getChildren()) {
      DataClass DataClass = dSnapshot.getValue(DataClass.class);
      list.add(0, DataClass);
   }
}
adapter = new ShowDetails.DataAdapter(ShowDetails.this, list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: still not working..it show all data randomly

Comment: Why r u using 2 loops? Remove one

Comment: because my data store in child node so i have to iterate from parent node

Comment: it adds elements to list on every iterator in parent loop, i think there's the problem,
maybe you should share the response.

Comment: please see my database structure. if i remove extra for loop, it retrive recycler view with empty value

Comment: see my edited answer, and if it works, i would appreciate if you upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: this answer will work for only one node

Comment: check my edited answer.

Comment: thank you... thank you...thank you so much...you just save my day <3 <3 <3

Comment: your welcome :) , and please upvote my answer

Comment: Already did.. :)

Comment: i can't upvote your answer because my reputation is below 15 :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207970/discussion-between-vahan-mambreyan-and-blackcoder).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: If your recycler view is displaying the data in reverse order..you can use the following method.

this will display in order if above condition meets

in your layout manager of your recycler view

```
LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);
```

this should solve your problem